# Search string with multiple words in the pattern

Tags: perl

My program is trying to search a string from multiple files in a directory. The code searches for single patterns like `perl` but fails to search a long string like `Status Code 1`.

Can you please let me know how to search for strings with multiple words?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @list = `find /home/ad -type f -mtime -1`;

# printf("Lsit is $list[1]\n");

foreach (@list) {

    # print("Now is : $_");

    open(FILE, $_);
    $_ = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);

    unless ($_ =~ /perl/) { # works, but fails to find string "Status Code 1"
        print "found\n";

        my $filename = 'report.txt';
        open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
        say $fh "My first report generated by perl";
        close $fh;

    } # end unless

} # end For
```

Comment: You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write

Comment: That goes double if you're posting it asking for assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code

- You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program. There is little point in delcaring anything with `my` without `strict` in place
- The lines returned by the `find` command will have a newline at the end which must be removed before Perl can find the files
- You should use *lexical file handles* (`my $fh` instead of `FILE`) and the three-parameter form of `open` as you do with your output file
- `$_ = <FILE>` reads only the *first* line of the file into `$_`
- `unless ($_ =~ /perl/)` is inverted logic, and there's no need to specify `$_` as it is the default. You should write `if ( /perl/ )`
- You can't use `say` unless you have `use feature 'say'` at the top of your program (or `use 5.010`, which adds all features available in Perl v5.10)

It is also best to avoid using shell commands as Perl is more than able to do anything that you can using command line utilities. In this case `-f $file` is a test that returns *true* if the file is a plain file, and `-M $file` returns the (floating point) number of days since the file's modification time

This is how I would write your program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

for my $file ( glob '/home/ad/*' ) {

    next unless -f $file and int(-M $file) == 1;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        if ( /perl/ ) {

            print "found\n";

            my $filename = 'report.txt';
            open my $out_fh, '>>', $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
            say $fh "My first report generated by perl";
            close $out_fh;

            last;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Original script does recurse, so `File::Find` might be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
unless ($_ =~ /perl/) {
```

to:

```
unless ($_ =~ /(Status Code 1)/) {
```

I am certain the above works, except it's case sensitive.
Since you question it, I rewrote your script to make more sense of what you're trying to accomplish and implement the above suggestion. Correct me if I am wrong, but you're trying to make a script which matches "Status Code 1" in a bunch of files where last modified within 1 day and print the filename to a text file.
Anyways, below is what I recommend:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $output_file = 'report.txt';
my @list = `find /home/ad -type f -mtime -1`;

foreach my $filename (@list) {
        print "PROCESSING: $filename";
        open (INCOMING, "<$filename") || die "FATAL: Could not open '$filename' $!";
        foreach my $line (<INCOMING>) {

                if ($line =~ /(Status Code 1)/) {
                        open( FILE, ">>$output_file") or die "FATAL: Could not open '$output_file' $!";
                        print FILE sprintf ("%s\n", $filename);
                        close(FILE) || die "FATAL: Could not CLOSE '$output_file' $!";

                        # Bail when we get the first match
                        last;
                }
        }
        close(INCOMING) || die "FATAL: Could not close '$filename' $!";
}
```

Comment: unless ($_ =~ /(Status Code 1)/) { - didn't work for me

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.. I find the issue when I use the line "my $entire_file_as_string = <INCOMING>;" printing "$entire_file_as_string" variable prints only has the first line of the each file, it should print all lines of the given file.. While the code works the functionality breaks as the  "if($entire_file_as_string =~ /(Exit Status 1)/) {" only compares the first line of each file and not the entire file.

Comment: Yeps, half asleep here, and I rushed that solution. Rejigged and refactored. Change the line regexp to a nested loop and a quick bail out option as soon as the string is found.

BTW, as a side recommendation, something like this would be quicker as a bash shell script, because you can grep for the String in the entire file vs reading it line by line

Comment: Ever since Perl v5.8 twenty years ago it has been preferable to use lexical file handles  and the three-parameter form of `open`. It's also wrong to put solitary scalar variables inside quotes, so `open (INCOMING, "<$filename")` should be `open my $incoming, '<', $filename`

Comment: `print FILE sprintf ("%s\n", $filename)` is usually written as `printf FILE "%s\n", $filename` or just `print FILE "$filename\n"`

Answer (score 0):

it should have matched unless $_ contains text in different case.

try this.

```
unless($_ =~ /Status\s+Code\s+1/i) {
```

Comment: Case was matched correctly. This also didn't work: unless($_ =~ /Status\s+Code\s+1/i)